# Blackberry File Invocation

Tags: file, blackberry, invocation

Why this won't work on a device but it works on a bb simulator.
Do you have any suggestions to make it work on the device?

```
   Invocation invocation = new Invocation("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/music/song.mp3"); 
   Registry reg = Registry.getRegistry("net.rim.device.api.content.BlackBerryContentHandler");
   reg.invoke(invocation);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors to evaluate the issue? Usually an error can give a clue.

Comment: @Arhimed No errors no exceptions thrown just no action performed ... very peculiar

Comment: sorry, in this case I'm helpless..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by registering not the content handler but the application package.
In my case:

```
Registry _registry=Registry.getRegistry("myapp.mobile.app");
```

Comment: great! I use Registry.getRegistry(Application.getApplication().getClass().getName(), and it works. thank you!